# the site in digitalocean doesn't send letters to the email

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I have a site in digitalocean hosting and I have some problems sending email from this site.
My site built at wordpress and I'm trying to submit an application to email. It worked on my localhost and my on my server https://cp.beget.com/  but as soon as I transferred it on https://www.digitalocean.com/ it immediately stopped working.

I have a small php script for send emails and it works correctly also I tried change admin email in main wp settings but I havу not received confirm letter on my email.

Server using ubuntu and i set everything up on it for email send and tested this through postfix and it worked correctly.

Maybe someone had this problem and know how it fix

Comment: Some cloud providers block sending mails from compute instances/droplets due to fear of instances being used as spam bots. Contact Digital Ocean support and get further assistance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use SMTP instead of relying php's `sendmail` which may get blocked on some hosting companies.

You can use the [Post SMTP Mailer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-smtp/) plugin to overcome this problem.

Just create a new email account at digitalocean and use its smtp server as the outgoing server address at the SMTP plugin. Usually it will be `mail.yourdomain.com`. Outgoing port can be 25 or 587.

Comment: `sendmail` will go to spam 99.9999% of the time. A SMTP plugin is required, like you said.